# Find the highest degree of A that divides N factorial

Tags: python

I've been working on this code to find the max exponent of A that divides into N! but it doesn't seem to be working. I've gotten to the point where I can find the different factors but I just get the same empty array returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
import math
def highestPower(N,A):
    factors = []
    x = math.factorial(N)
    for i in range(0,N,-1):
        if x % A**i == 0:
            factors += [i]
    return factors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid computing the exponentiation, get rid of the `for` loop, just divide as long as you can.

```
import math
def highestPower(N,A):
    result = 0
    x = math.factorial(N)
    while x % A == 0:
      x /= A
      result += 1
    return result
```

You could also avoid computing the factorial with a loop from 1 to N.

Answer (score 0):

Your `range` is reversed:

```
for i in range(0,N,-1):
```

Should be:

```
for i in range(N,0,-1):
```

Also, if you only require the **highest**, you can return immediately:

```
import math
def highestPower(N,A):
    x = math.factorial(N)
    for i in range(0, N, -1):
        if x % A**i == 0:
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

Range should be `range(N,0,-1):`
The docs for range say:

> if `step` is negative, the last element is the smallest `start + i * step` greater than `stop`

So, you need to have `start` > `stop` if your step is negative. Otherwise, the for loop does not run at all.